# What is meant by the phrase "but the identity in a quotient group is the subgroup" in this Abstract Algebra proof?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, quotient-group

I was reading *How to Think about Abstract Algebra* by Lara Alcock, and encountered the following theorem and proof in the section on Lagrange's Theorem:

> Claim: Let $K = \{e, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23) \trianglelefteq S_4 \}$. Then for every $g \in S_4, g^6 \in K$.
>
> Proof: Because K is normal, $S_4/K$ is a quotient group.
> By Lagrange's Theorem, there are 24/4 = 6 cosets of $K$ in $S_4$.
> So the quotient group $S_4/K$ has order 6.
> Let $g \in S_4$ be arbitrary and note that $S_4/K$ has element $gK$.
> Then, by the previous theorem [which states that, if group G has order $n$, then $g^n=e$ for all $g \in G$], $(gK)^6$ is equal to the identity in $S_4/K$.
> **But the identity in a quotient group is the subgroup, in this case $K$.**
> So $(gK)^6 = K = g^6K = K$.
> So $g^6 = K$ for every $g \in G$.

I don't understand exactly what the highlighted sentence means or why it is, though. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: The inverse image of the identity under the usual map from the group to the quotient group is the relevant subgroup.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez That became clear to me after I read the answer, but the way the textbook phrased it I didn't understand that that's what they were referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quotient group $S/K$ is a group where the elements are the cosets of $K$ in $S$. (Left or right cosets? Doesn't matter, quotient groups are only constructed when $K$ is normal, and thus right cosets are left cosets and vice versa, and we can just talk about cosets without specifying direction.) The identity element in $S/K$ is the coset of $K$ that is just $K$ itself.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, thanks - I see the book's point now.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque I'm not disputing that my question is a duplicate, but the answer clarifies things for me more than the dupe target does (because the way that the textbook phrased it I didn't understand that that's what the author was referring to).